# Does AudioQueueReset free audio buffers, or simply return them?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm working on an application that handles sound at the Audio Queue Services level, in iOS.

**Context**:
I have an audio queue that's started and playing fine. I have a few buffers enqueued for continuous playback.

**Need**:
I need to cancel the playback instantly and dequeue the buffers (the next sound played will be different). I cannot use `AudioQueueStop`, as I still need the `AudioQueue` for more audio playback stuff instantly.

So I resorted to use `AudioQueueReset`. My output callback is properly called, and returns all the buffers.

But when I try to reuse these buffers with `AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer`, I get an `OSStatus` of 50, meaning that the argument is invalid.

tl;dr: **Does `AudioQueueReset` only return buffers ready for use, or frees them and I have to reallocate new buffers?**

Answer (score 0):

It only returns them. The buffers are ready for use, and not freed.